# Unsure how to use a given data type

Tags: haskell, algebraic-data-types

I'm doing some homework and I have to use the following definition:

```
data Ponto = Cartesiano Double Double | Polar Double Double deriving (Show,Eq)
```

to write a function that calculates the distance of a point to the vertical axis, the coordinates can be as x and y or r and angle using the data type above.

Can you help me understand how I should use this type of definition in Haskell?

Comment: How are you _currently_ trying to use the data type? Edit your question to add what you've got so far. Also, indent code snippet by 4 spaces to get code highlighting.

Comment: Can you share what is not working with the current attempt?

Comment: I have one class about haskell and I was doing homework and I don't know how to use this kind of data with multiple definion, I don't want to someone to do it for me just a quick explanation how to use this right!

Comment: Do you know how you would write the function if the definition were simply `data Ponto = Cartesiano Double Double`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to define the function piecewise for each data constructor available for the type:

```
yourFunction :: Numa a => Ponto -> a
yourFunction (Cartesiano x y) = ...
yourFunction (Polar r th) = ...
```